# ImportError: cannot import name 'init_android_package' from 'create_package'

Tags: python, tensorflow, ros

After installing tes nsorflow2.0, I use catkin_make to compile a ROS package with .pt file. It is wrong.

```
import rosjava_build_tools
```

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosjava_build_tools/**init**.py", line 8, in 
    from create_package import init_android_package, init_rosjava_package
ImportError: cannot import name 'init_android_package' from 'create_package' (/home/lyg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/create_package/**init**.py)
turtlebot3_msgs/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/build.make:69: recipe for target 'turtlebot3_msgs/java/turtlebot3_msgs/build.gradle' failed
make[2]: *** [turtlebot3_msgs/java/turtlebot3_msgs/build.gradle] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:816: recipe for target 'turtlebot3_msgs/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [turtlebot3_msgs/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/all] Error 2

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you are trying to do. Can you give some more context? Which version of ros are you using? What are you trying to compile? Are you using tensorflow in python or in Java? Are you trying to create an android package? I can not tell the context which you ran this line of code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was using ROS kinetic (16.04) .Now that I delete "  \export PATH="/home/lyg/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"" in bashrc file ,The ROS package can be comfiled successfully. But I can't use anaconda3 anymore.What should I do to use them  meanwhile?

Comment: Ah. That is a python development question: use 'virtualenvs'. Anaconda has a way [built in to make virtual envs](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/). Every python project you use, outside of ros, should be in its own virtualenv, to not conflict with other projects. ros (mostly) needs to use the built in system python, so you can't (easily) use a different python version for it, but you can use a virtual env for any libraries. If you don't really need to use anaconda, you can just use normal system (2.7) python/virtualenvs. Let me know how else to help.